# How to get blazemeter output report link to slack

Tags: jmeter, slack, blazemeter, taurus

I am using Jmeter with Tauras and tests are running through Bitbucket pipeline. I have managed to get passfail criteria and Blazemeter output report url is displayed with the results inside Bitbucket. Is it possible if I can extract that URL and get the result URL in slack to have better slack notification?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can redirect your Taurus output into a file, i.e.

   ```
    bzt test.yaml -report > foo.txt
   ```
2. The file can be [saved as a step artifact](https://%20https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-artifacts-in-steps/)
3. There is [slack-notify](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/slack-notify/src/master/) pipe which you can use for sending a custom message, report link can be extracted from Taurus output using grep command, something like:

   ```
   grep -oP -m1 'https?://a\.blazemeter[^ ]+' foo.txt
   ```
4. [BlazeMeter has its own Slack alerts](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13382478607889-Creating-Workspace-Alerts#h_01F4Z6WYGR2ZJRA0Y118A3REMZ) as well.